# ¿Cómo extraigo todo el texto a partir del segundo "_"?

Tags: shell-script, grep, awk, cut

Estoy haciendo un comando en linux que me retorna una salida, el comando es el siguiente:

```
ps -fea | grep ora_pmon | awk 'length($9) > 2 {print $9}'
```

y su salida es la siguiente:

```
ora_pmon
ora_pmon_test
ora_pmon_PRUEBA
ora_pmon_test_1
```

Estoy tratando de que el resultado sea:

```
test
PRUEBA
test_1
```

Lo otro es que al borrar el "ora_pmon" me queda una linea en blanco en el resultado. ¿Cóomo se podría quitar?

Comment: Sería bueno dar texto y no imágenes. Además, siempre es sacar lo último o lo tercero tras la `_`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una solución que se me ocurre rápidamente es usando sencillas expresiones regulares.

```
ps -fea | grep -Po 'ora_pmon_\K.*'
```

Donde el parámetro `-P` habilita las expresiones regulares tipo *PERL*, entonces podemos usar el metacaracter `'\K'`. El parámetro `-o` imprime únicamente lo que empareje.

En la expresión regular `'ora_pmon_\K.*'` con el metacaracter `\K` el motor pretende que inició desde esa posición, es decir, una vez que encuentra la lista 'ora_pmon_' empieza desde ahí, y con `.*` selecciona todo lo que esté después.

Puedes intentar de esta manera si no acepta el parámetro `-P`

```
... | grep -o 'ora_pmon_.*' | cut -d _ -f 3-
```

Es decir, con el caracter `-` después del número 3. Sejemante a lo que @fedorqui puso en su respuesta.

Por un momento olvidé al buen `sed`, también podrías utilizarlo.

```
... | sed -rn 's/(.*)(ora_pmon_)(.*)/\3/p'
```

Comment: `{if ($3) print $3}` se puede simplificar a solamente `{$3 {print $3}`. De todos modos, asumes que solamente habrá estas _ en toda la línea y puede noser así. El AP está imprimiendo solamente $9.

Comment: Tienes razón, deja aclaro algunas cosas por lo mientras.

Comment: Mi sistema operativo no es compatible con grep -P

Comment: @JesúsHenríquez Entonces tendrías que aclarar eso en tu pregunta, es decir, el sistema operativo que usas. De todas maneras prueba con la nueva sugerencia.

Comment: Nótese que lo de cut ya lo indicaba en mi respuesta

Comment: Bueno, como siempre +1 por la respuesta, completa y útil. Dicho lo cual, no me gustó el hecho de que usaras la parte que yo ya había indicado con `cut`, no es buena práctica aquí en Stack Overflow.

Comment: Tienes razón, sólo que en la primera versión de tu respuesta como no incluías el guión después del `3-`, que creo que eso era lo fundamental, lo supuse como respuesta independiente, aunque similar. Aunque lo referiré en mi próxima edición.

Answer (score 1):

Es decir, buscas imprimir el tercer campo resultante de cortar la cadena en base al carácter `_`. Para ello, simplemente di:

```
... | cut -d'_' -f3
```

Es decir, corta por `_` e imprime el tercero.

---

Comentas que:

> El tema es que si el resultado es ora_pmon_TEST_1, solo me mostraria TEST y necesito que muestre TEST_1

Por tanto, no es que quieras el tercer bloque, sino a partir del tercero. Por ello, simplemente digámosle a `cut` que imprima todo a partir del n-ésimo con `-fn-`. En este caso, `-f3-`.

Simplifico además el `grep | awk` en una sola cosa, para dejarlo en:

```
ps -fea | awk '/ora_pmon/ length($9) > 2 {print $9}' | cut -d'_' -f3-
```

Comment: El tema es que si el resultado es ora_pmon_TEST_1, solo me mostraria TEST y necesito que muestre TEST_1

Comment: @JesúsHenríquez por ello te pedí que dieras ejemplos claros y representativos.